# GetTwitter stops fetching data from Twitter after few hours

Tags: apache, twitter, apache-nifi, tweets

I used GetTwitter processor in Apache Nifi to process live tweets using UserId. Initially it works fine but after few hours no tweets is retrieved from Twitter.
May I know why I am getting this issue.

**Note:**
Since I am using 25000 user id to fetch live tweets from them. As I referred some blogs it shows 5000 UserId is maximum limit for GetTwitter processor. I used 5 GetTwitter processor with same access credentias to divide the 25000 user ids to 5 parts.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are encountering a rate limiting issue.  Twitter's documentation on it can be found at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting

Comment: Can confirm that if you are pulling from an API like twitter with Nifi, and it suddenly stops working...it is always the API squeezing you off.